# ListView in WinJS jumps back when height and width specified on listItem

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-8.1, winjs

I'm trying to achieve something very simple with WinJS. I want the items in a `listView` to occupy the full height of the viewport.

I can achieve this by overriding the default styles for the `listView` like this:

```
.win-itemscontainer {
    width: 100% !important;
    height: calc(100vh - 1px) !important;
}
.win-horizontal .win-gridlayout .win-container {
    height: calc(20% - 1px);
    margin: 0 0 1px 1px;
    outline: none;
}
.win-listview {
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.win-listview .item {
    width: 250px;
}
```

This works fine and renders 5 rows of list items. The list then scrolls if the number of items exceeds the containers width.

However, there are some very odd behaviours occurring. If I scroll to the very end of the `listView`, something causes the scroll position to jump back making the last row in the listView unattainable because the jump prevents me from ever reaching it.

Is there a better way of achieving what I'm after or is there a way to fix what I've implemented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was never able to sufficiently answer this so I switched from a listView to a repeater which gave me greater control over the markup and CSS.